# teradata SQL tuning pundits - SELECT Failed. 3771: Illegal expression in WHEN clause of CASE expression

Tags: sql, case, teradata, exists, sql-tuning

I am using a statement as below and get this error:

> SELECT Failed. 3771:  Illegal expression in WHEN clause of CASE
>   expression.

I had better hopes from Teradata.  SQL Server can do it but Teradata can't.
How can I work around this?  Any solution?

```
sel ( CASE
    WHEN  EXISTS   ( sel '1' from VolatileTable Dtb1 where Dtb1.c1=FACT_Table_5MillionRows.C1)
    THEN "FACTTablew5MillionRows"."CustomColumName" 
ELSE 'ALL OTHER'
END  ) (NAMED "CustomColumName" )

from
"Db"."FACTTablew5MillionRows"
```

Comment: FOLKS how abt if I LOJ the "FACTTablew5MillionRows" and  VolatileTable Dtb1 and  then do when  Dtb1.c1=FACT_Table_5MillionRows.C1  then  "_____"  else "___" WOuld that afford equivalence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teradata doesn't like EXISTS in Correlated Scalar Subqueries within a CASE, but you can rewrite it like this:

```
select
  ( CASE
       WHEN C1 = ( select MIN(C1) from VolatileTable Dtb1 
                   where Dtb1.c1=ft.C1)
       THEN ft."CustomColumName" 
       ELSE 'ALL OTHER'
    END  ) (NAMED "CustomColumName" )
from
"Db"."FACTTablew5MillionRows" as ft
```

If `VolatileTable.C1` is unique you can remove the `MIN`.

But in 95% logic like this can be replaced by a LEFT JOIN:

```
select
   ft.*,
   CASE WHEN Dtb1.c1 IS NOT NULL 
        THEN ft."CustomColumName" 
        ELSE  'ALL OTHER' 
   end as "CustomColumName" 
from "Db"."FACTTablew5MillionRows" as ft
left join VolatileTable Dtb1 
on Dtb1.c1=ft.C1
```

This will return duplicated rows if `VolatileTable.C1` is not unique, then you need to change it to:

```
from "Db"."FACTTablew5MillionRows" as ft
left join (select distinct C1 from VolatileTable) Dtb1 
on Dtb1.c1=ft.C1
```

Comment: Hi Dieter the LOJ was what I was thinking about and implemented it.But I quite dont get the 1st approach 1 `select
  ( CASE
       WHEN C1 = ( select MIN(C1) from VolatileTable Dtb1 
                   where Dtb1.c1=ft.C1)
       THEN ft."CustomColumName" 
       ELSE 'ALL OTHER'
    END  ) (NAMED "CustomColumName" )
from
"Db"."FACTTablew5MillionRows" as ft`  .Min ( Col) will be a constant not the same as a what the LOJ would do right ?

Comment: TY Dieter. I updated my other Q's right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877616/teradata-sql-tuning-with-sum-and-other-aggregate-functions

Comment: and  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004757/teradata-sql-optimization-not-in-list-col-and-in-list-optimization

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
WHEN EXISTS (...)
```

By

```
WHEN 1 = (SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (...))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHEN  EXISTS (select '1' from VolatileTable Dtb1 
              where Dtb1.c1=FACT_Table_5MillionRows.C1)
THEN somevalue --or a statement that yields a scalar value
```

You were selecting a column in the `then` part, where you should be assigning a unique value.

Comment: There is not problem selecting a column in the `then` part of a `case` statement.

Comment: Yes . EVEN the  answer suggestion does not work  this gives the same error `sel  ( case WHEN  EXISTS (select '1' from VolatileTable Dtb1 
              where Dtb1.c1=FACT_Table_5MillionRows.C1 ) then 'Flag'  ELSE 'flag2'  END )`

Comment: I agree with Gordon. We do it all the time

Comment: should sel be select instead?

Comment: Gordon..i answered so because i thought it was selecting all the values in that column,which wouldn't work in then. I am not sure about quoting strings in teradata though.