# Teradata SQL Optimization : NOT IN ( List ) , Col <> and IN LIST Optimization

Tags: sql, performance, relational-database, teradata, sql-tuning

I have queries with a LOT of these situations

```
Sel TB1.C1
TB2.C2,
TB3.C4
Tb5.C5
where < Join conditions involving all tables TB1 through TB4 . 
Most are inner some are LOJ > 
where TB2.C2 NOT In ( List ) 
   OR TB3.C5 <> 'string' 
   OR Tb5.C8 NOT IN ( another long list )
```

Is there a better way to  rewrite the filter conditions

```
NOT IN ( List ) ,   Col <> and IN LIST Optimization
```

some of the cols are selected some are not  which are there in the sel Vs the filter condition.

Comment: Have you considered put your lists into VOLATILE tables and using NOT EXISTS clauses? This would allow the optimizer to use an EXCLUSION MERGE JOIN and may perform better.

Comment: I am aware of Volatile table for IN LISTS. The problem with VT's is that they entail an additional step and many 3rd party BI tools are not VT friendly . Coming to NOT exists  where the  "where clause column" is part of select - how do I get this done. `WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( sel '1' from TB3 3 where <Join on all PI cols> and 3.tb3='string')` is how I think it should look . Problem here is I am calling TB3 a big FAT table twice. Would that be performance saavy compared to using it once ? UNLESS I am missing something in implementing NOT exists and you can PL help me here

Comment: Have you tried CASE_N partitioning of tables? In case the data permits such partitioning without impacting other jobs, this can result in a performance boost at select time with minimal storage and insertion overheads