# Illegal Expression In WHEN of CASE Expression : How to solve this error

Tags: sql, teradata

i have error in teradata that say :

> Illegal Expression In WHEN of CASE Expression

Here is my data :
[image: enter link description here]

And that's my query :

```
 SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Country='UK' AND Customer IN (SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM table WHERE 
    Customer<>'A') THEN 'EUR' ELSE 'OTHER' END AS Continent_E
 FROM table
```

Suppose that in my real data there are 20 distinct customers that are different to A, how can i write the query to not have an error

Can you help me
Kind regards

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as properly formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Within a CASE you can only use Correlated Scalr Subqueries, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32985863/2527905, but there might be better solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teradata does not allow `IN (subquery)` within a `CASE` expression. If you need this type of logic, you could use outer join pattern instead:

```
SELECT T.*,
    CASE WHEN Country='UK' 
      AND X.Customer IS NOT NULL /* Outer Join found a match */
    THEN 'EUR' 
    ELSE 'OTHER' END AS Continent_E
 FROM myTable T
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM CustTable WHERE Customer<>'A') X
 ON T.Customer = X.Customer;
```

Comment: Within CASE you could use a correlated scalar subquery (one that returns a single value per "outer" row) or a non-correlated scalar subquery (which returns only one row / one value) and do some other conditional test (e.g. equality) with that returned value. But that seems an additional level of complication.

Answer (score 1):

A `subquery` inside `case` clause is not accepted, your query can simply be like this :

```
 SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN Country='UK' AND Customer <> 'A' THEN 'EUR' ELSE 'OTHER' END AS Continent_E
 FROM table
```

Result :

```
customer    country          Continent_E
A           India            OTHER
A           USA              OTHER
A           USA              OTHER
B           UK               EUR
C           UK               EUR
D          JAPAN             OTHER
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I still have the error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to rename your table name. Because in SQL, "table" is a reserved word.
Or you can add [] to the table name([table]). In SQL Server, the query executes successfully although it still renders "Invalid valid object name 'table' " warning. But in MySQL Workbench, it fails.

Comment: Firstly, op probably just used `table` instead of the actual table name. Second, in Teradata someone did want to use a reserved word as an object name, they would need to use  double quotes.